# Is is possible to use Chayos as Korbanos

Tags: halacha, animals, korban

I'm assuming all issues of Kashrus and Shechita aside - i.e. We have a mesora for Shechting a Giraffe, is it possible to use say, a Giraffe, or Tzvi or Ayal as a Korban, b'sha'as Adchak or are the specific animals mentioned in the Torah those specifically and not any others, even bidi'eved?

Comment: What did you mean by *"We have a mesora for Shechting a Giraffe"*?

Comment: There are differing opinions on whether or not you need a *mesora* for shechting chayos as with birds.  The mention was to avoid this point.  I'm not interested to know whether it is permitted or not vis a vis kashrus, that wasn't the question here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Rambam Mishneh Torah, Hilchot Ma'aseh HaKorbanot 1:1](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Sacrificial_Procedure.1.1?lang=bi):

> כָּל הַקָּרְבָּנוֹת שֶׁל מִינֵי נֶפֶשׁ חַיָּה בָּאִין מֵחֲמִשָּׁה מִינִין **בִּלְבַד**. מִן הַבָּקָר וּמִן הַכְּבָשִׂים וּמִן הָעִזִּים וּמִן הַתּוֹרִים וּמִן בְּנֵי הַיּוֹנָה:‏
>
> All sacrifices of living creatures come from the following five species **only**: Cattle, sheep, goats, turtle doves and young doves.

There is no option given of using any other species, under any circumstances.

Comment: I didn't know   הַבֹּקֶר means cattle. Live and learn.

Comment: the root is בקר but you raise an interesting point about the relationship between בקר as in morning, and בקר  as in cattle or beef.

Comment: @User6591 Well spotted. Fixed

Comment: @Danny F t'was a joke about the nekudos from that site. Maybe there is a connection....

Comment: @user6591 כי בוקר אנכי ובולס שקמים it means cowboy

Comment: @Double Ah. Human sacrifice? Nice.

Comment: @user6591 I am aware, but I didn't read it with nekudos - they're the same letters.